# Is there a way to append the associated filename, column name and datatype of values in each column in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
headerList=["Type","Column Name"]
    
df.dtypes.to_csv(f, header=headerList)
```

This return an error

```
ValueError: Writing 1 cols but got 2 aliases
```

is there any way I can add a header and get all the data for a dataframe in a csv file that looks like this

```
FileName     ColumnName  DataType

dataset.xls  Name       Object   
dataset.xls  Gender     Object
dataset.xls  Occupation Object
.
.
```

Edit: df.dtypes outputs a 1d series where the index is the column name and the type is the value. Got the answer from reddit

```
df.dtypes.to_csv(f, index_label="Column Name", header=["Type"])
```

this works!

Comment: `df.dtypes.reset_index().set_axis(headerList[::-1],axis=1).to_csv(....)` does this work?

Comment: No Its returning this - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'